# Prevent user screenshot like ScreenShieldKit

Tags: swift, screenshot

How can I protect against a user taking a screenshot using the Top/Side + Home/Volume up buttons on the device like ScreenShieldKit https://screenshieldkit.com/

I want a black screen before user take a screenShot.

Example of ScreendShield web site

```
import ScreenShieldKit

let label = SSKProtectedLabel(text: "Hello World")
view.addSubview(label)

let image = UIImage(named: "MyImage")
let imageView = SSKProtectedImageView(image: image)
view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Comment: So why can't you just use this library?

Comment: Because this option is paid and I would like to have a programmatic solution, but with the same effect of that library, you know any way?

Comment: This question has been [asked many times](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+prevent+screenshot). Please review those search results.

Comment: @M.Mansueli can you tell me the price of this library ?